# Android & Google Play publishing for customers

Tags: android, google-play

I am currently working on an Android app and I am wondering which would be the best way to distribute it to customers. I understand that one can create a private channel but I haven't been able to determine whether our customers would be able to use it. From what I've gathered, a private channel is for internal distribution; I wonder if someone without an e-mail account from our company would be able to download it this way?

If Google Play is not the answer, what would you do? I know the app can be distributed through e-mail or links to download it but I'd rather avoid having users change their devices' configuration to allow installing APK from unknown sources.

Comment: You can download .apk as beta in developer Panel. Then add Google+ Circle for test. All peoples from this circle can download this App from GP.

Comment: Thank you! However, will users be warned that this is simply a testing version when installing the app or anything like that?

Comment: They will receive message that they was allowed to test app, with link to GP.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your beef with Google Play is but even if you're not intending to publish the app at all, you can still take advantage of the beta testing mechanism -- you can distribute a Google Play to limited audience -- i.e. a list of google accounts.

<s>Apart from that, if I'm not mistaken [TestFlight](https://www.testflightapp.com/) supports Android package distribution.</s> Looks like they dropped Android support

Comment: Hi! We use TestFlight for iOS but they stopped supporting Android recently. :(

Comment: @DavidMartín Ah, too bad :/